# HexString "0x05" to Hex Number 0x05 Lua

Tags: string, lua, numbers, type-conversion, hex

How can I in Lua

from HexString `"0x05"` to Convert Hex  `0x05` number?

I need a hex number like this 0x05 ! Type = number

No string! Not the number 5!

Comment: Not the number 5??

Answer (score 1):

Use `tonumber("0x05")`:

```
print(tonumber("0x05") == 0x05)
```

Comment: Nailed it. +0x01.